# Jquery .animate slows with use when using jquery event listeners

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, mobile, ibm-mobilefirst

I am building a hybrid mobile application using Jquery event listeners with touch support to create interactions however I am having a problem with event listeners calling functions that use `.animate`. The first `animate` works fine but the second time it is slower and the third time even more slower. Looking at logs it seems the event listener is multiplying the calls to the function by 2 each time it's called.

I've narrowed the problem down to the event listener as the function work flawlessly when called manually in chrome dev tools. I have tried using jquery `.on` and `.one` event listeners. Below is my code, it would be great to get some advice on this...

The HTML

```
<div id="closeIcon"></div>
```

and the JS...

```
$('#closeIcon').one("tap", closeLogin);

function closeLogin(){
$('#userContainer').animate({'padding-top': '120px'}, 500);
$('#contentContainer').animate({'height': '682px'}, 500, function(){
    unselectUser();
    $('#loginContainer').empty();
    $('#loginContainer').css('visibility', "hidden");
});
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('#closeIcon').one("tap", closeLogin);

function closeLogin(e){
    e.stopImmediatePropagation();

    $('#userContainer').animate({'padding-top': '120px'}, 500);
    $('#contentContainer').animate({'height': '682px'}, 500, function(){
        unselectUser();
        $('#loginContainer').empty();
        $('#loginContainer').css('visibility', "hidden");
    });
}
```